# Find machines on local network based on port (network discover) in android

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I am looking to have my android app scan every PC on the local network 192.168.1.1-254 looking for machines with some given port open. I know of a few manual ways to do this, but it would be a ton of code and would take a while each time it needs to search. Is there a quick way to specify a port and search for local devices with it open?

Ex. Desktop has web server on port 8888, you know the port but not the IP, give the app the port and have it quickly show you the IP.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you know how to connect to a tcp server.
If not, First go through

> http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

You can try opening multiple threads with each thread waiting to connect to a specific ip/port ( along with some timeout value ).If the thread produces an exception, that means the connection was unsuccesful. Othewise add that ip address to your Open_Devices list.